# google maps to display friendly inline error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, popup

The main problem here is when license key is invalid, google maps api will return an annoying javascript popup alert box.

Since this is deployed to multiple users and each user need to register the google maps license by themselves, is there any way to detect the annoying popup message and change it into friendly inline div?

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=00000000AIzaSyAeST3KV26OghAb7TE7qiNXVQCWGkKSN9s" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script language="javascript"> load();addMarker( "(Unknown City?), (Unknown Country?)", "IP (aa)", "../images/marker_purple.png");addMarker( "", "IP (bb)", "../images/marker_red.png");addMarker( "test address 2", "Billing & Shipping Address", "../images/marker_green.png");</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem - what is wrong with each user of your code registering their own key?

Comment: it is a script that each user can download it and put it into their hosting, then DIY generate their own license key to put in. As long as user keep didn't generate key, then will keep on javascript popup error. I would like to change it to a more friendly inline html error.

Comment: Surely that's a very good reminder for them to go and get a licence key?! The app isn't going to work without the key anyway, so you might as well have a very obtuse way of reminding them

Comment: I also want to do the same thing. In my case I want to display a different inline message because I don't need the user to go to developers.google.com. I want them to contact my company to resolve the issue.